# Python FastAPI "Post Unprocessable Entity" error

Tags: python, html, fastapi

Getting error when to submit button

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel
from googletrans import Translator

import uvicorn

#from googletrans import Translator
#init
app = FastAPI(debug=True)

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="template")


#route
@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
        data = {'request': request}
        return templates.TemplateResponse('translates.html', data)


class variable(BaseModel):
    Input_text: str
    trans: str

#def translator(request):
@app.post('/',response_model=variable)
async def trans(request: Request,  form: variable ):

    text = request.get('Input_text')
    lang = request.get('trans')
    # print('text:',text,'lang:',lang)

    # connect the translator
    translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'])

    # detect langguage
    dt = translator.detect(text)
    dt2 = dt.lang

    # translate the text
    translated = translator.translate(text, lang)
    tr = translated.text
    data = {
        'request': request,
        'translated': tr
        , 'u_lang': dt2
        , 't_lang': lang}

    return templates.TemplateResponse(data, "translates.html",)


if __name__=="__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app,host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

Then the HTML code

**translate.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Translate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui container">
    <h2>Translation</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    <br>

<div class="form-input">
    <center><label for="TextareaInput">Enter Text </label></center>
    <center><textarea class="form-control" name="Input_text" id="TextareaInput" rows="3"></textarea></center>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div class="selection list">
  <center><label for="languages">Choose Langguage:</label></center>
  <center><select name="trans" id="languages">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="ms">Malay</option>
    <option value="zh-cn">Mandarin</option>
    <option value="ko">Korean</option>
      <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
      <option value="vi">Vietnamese</option>
      <option value="th">Thailand</option>
  </select></center>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div>
   <center> <button type="Submit" class="button">Translate</button></center>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div class="form-output">
    <!---<center><textarea class="form-control" id="TextareaOutput" rows="3" value={{translated}} placeholder="Translate..."></textarea></center>-->

    <div class="Output Translation">

        <br><br>
        <h1>Text translated {{u_lang}} from {{t_lang}}</h1>
        <center>
            <h1>{{translated}}</h1>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to button submit these happen ->

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
      "type": "value_error.jsondecode",
      "ctx": {
        "msg": "Expecting value",
        "doc": "Input_text=hi&trans=zh-cn",
        "pos": 0,
        "lineno": 1,
        "colno": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Pretty sure the error occurs on my BaseModel parameter but I seem can't get it corrected, already search on the internet tho.

Comment: ok turn out i need to put context={} on return example  return templates.TemplateResponse('translates.html', context=data) n for post

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pydantic` models for a request body parameters, FastAPI [interprets](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#results) them as `json` objects:

> With just that Python type declaration, FastAPI will:
>
> - Read the body of the request **as JSON**.
> - Convert the corresponding types (if needed).
> - Validate the data...

But `HTML` forms are sent to the server not in the form of `json`, but in a special `x-www-form-urlencoded` format (more info [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/)), so to read the form values, you need to use the `Form` parameters, like so:

```
@app.post("/")
async def path_operation(Input_text: str = Form(...), trans: str = Form(...)):
    return {"Input_text": Input_text, "trans": trans}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Pydantic** models, but you need to create a workaround like this, it expects a **Body** by default, so we are changing the signature of the Fields by wrapping the Pydantic Model.

```py
from fastapi import Form, Depends


def form_body(cls):
    cls.__signature__ = cls.__signature__.replace(
        parameters=[
            arg.replace(default=Form(...))
            for arg in cls.__signature__.parameters.values()
        ]
    )
    return cls


@form_body
class variable(BaseModel):
    Input_text: str
    trans: str
```

Then you can start using it like this

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel


app = FastAPI(debug=True)


def form_body(cls):
    cls.__signature__ = cls.__signature__.replace(
        parameters=[
            arg.replace(default=Form(...))
            for arg in cls.__signature__.parameters.values()
        ]
    )
    return cls


@form_body
class variable(BaseModel):
    Input_text: str
    trans: str


@app.post("/", response_model=variable)
async def trans(form: variable = Depends(variable)):

    return form
```